# Borderlands 2 DLC's not downloading

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

How do I download or re-download DLC's like Son of Headhunter Pack 5 in Borderlands 2 for the Xbox 360? I try everything but its no use.

Comment: Which system are you playing the game on?

Comment: xbox 360 why do you ask

Comment: Have you purchased the DLC?

Comment: yes i did it still didnt do any thing

Comment: Sorry about my spelling.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish by linking Xbox 360 to a broken URL in your edit?

Comment: Im 13 sorry i did not mean to.

Comment: I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your account history on the xbox to make sure it was associated to the correct account and then download it.

This is found in Settings -> Account -> Download History.

http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/downloadable-content/view-download-history

If it happens that it was associated to the wrong account by accident, as long as the first xbox used by the associated account is the same one you are trying to play the content on, everyone on that Xbox should be able to use the content but you'll need to use the original purchaser account to download it.

Comment: Ok i understand.